# Can store updates be too quick for React to re-render?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, redux

I'm writing a React Redux web application that utilizes Redux-Saga for async. In the saga there are usually 2 actions that are dispatched:

- 1) SAVE_PENDING
- 2) SAVE_SUCCESS (Or SAVE_FAILURE in case of an error).

These two actions trigger a isSaving property in state to change from false to true and back to false. These changes all happens in less than 10ms. The web application utilizes websockets.

These state change DO NOT cause our React component to re-render. All other async functions and state changes are reflected correctly in the DOM except the Save function. My hypothesis is that the changes happen so quickly (9ms) that React doesn't feel the need to re-render the DOM since the DOM will only different for 9ms.

My redux logs look like so:

```
action @ 15:30:53.946 @@stuffz/morestuffz/SAVE
action @ 15:30:53.950 @@stuffz/morestuffz/SAVE_PENDING 
action @ 15:30:53.955 @@stuffz/morestuffz/SAVE_SUCCESS
```

Does this hypothesis sound correct? If so what would be the best way to get around this? I'm thinking just have isSaved remain true and reset it when a new save is triggered.

Edit: I've appended a shortened version of both the reducer and component. For the reducer we're utilizing ImmutableJS and arrow function to keep it neat. Also, you'll notice we didn't choose to have a separate container for mapping state and actions to props. In the componentWillReceiveProps method we're closing a modal and launching a notification if isSaving is updating from true to false. Thanks for the interest so far!

Reducer:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  isSaving: false,
  error: null,
  tracks: [],
  saves: []
})

export default function(state = initialState, action){
  const { type, payload } = action
  switch (type) {
    case actions.SAVE_SC_TRACKS_PENDING:
      return savePending(state)
    case actions.SAVE_SC_TRACKS_SUCCESS:
      return saveSuccess(state, payload)
    case actions.SAVE_SC_TRACKS_FAILURE:
      return saveFailure(state, payload)
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const savePending = state => state.set('isSaving', true)
const saveSuccess = (state, payload) => state.set('isSaving', false).set('saves', fromJS(payload.saves))
const saveFailure = (state, payload) => state.set('isSaving', false).set('error', payload)
```

Component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.app.socket.get('user'),
  scTracks: state.music.importer.get('scTracks'),
  isFetching: state.music.importer.get('isFetching'),
  isSaving: state.music.importer.get('isSaving'),
  error: state.music.importer.get('error')
})

@connect(mapStateToProps)
@isAuthenticated
export default class Importer extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context)
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // close model and launch notification
    if(this.props.isSaving && !nextProps.isSaving && !nextProps.error) {
      this.props.closeModal()
      $('body').pgNotification({ style: 'bar', message: 'Successfully saved!', type: 'success', position: 'top' }).show();
    }
  }
}
```

I did a little more digging and placed a 5 sec delay before the success action is dispatched and that seemed to solve the issue. Based off of that I assume the reason the component wasn't re-rendering was because of React's damn good DOM updating. I'll still leave the question open to answers in case anyone can explain how to solve this without making the async calls unnecessarily slow.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant store/reducer setup and the component which binds to the store/reducer? I doubt it is "too quick".

Comment: it could just be that people can't process changes that fast. When I've faced this in the past I'll log timestamps from the render to verify if something is rerendering or not. But react is pretty wicked performant for stuff like styling changes.

Comment: @MarioTacke I went ahead and appended our reducer and component. To keep it short I've cleared the reducer and code of unnecessary functions. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @TheBrofessor That's what I suspect too, but I haven't been able to come across any docs or posts that talk about React's behavior when state changes so quickly. Hopefully others on the site can help out.

Comment: I've never seen this syntax to modify the state (`state.set`). Out of curiosity, have you tried returning a new state object in your reducer? Example `SAVE_SC_TRACKS_PENDING`: `return Object.assign({}, state, { isSaving: true })`

Comment: @MarioTacke It's a method that is specific  to ImmutableJS https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/set